# Ubuntu touchpad setting not working

Tags: touchpad, 22.04, settings

The Ubuntu touchpad settings are not working after an upgrade to 22.04.

1. When the touchpad is turned off from the touchpad settings, the touchpad is left on.
2. Changing the setting of natural scrolling does not work.
3. Before upgrade, a three finger tap would open a web link in a new browser tab, but it does not work now.

Comment: How did you upgrade to 22.04? From which release?

Answer (score 5):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

and reboot.

Comment: Hi, if I understand well, this command uninstall a touchpad driver right? Why is this a solution, and why is it not necessary to install another driver after?